# Idiomatic combinations of peanut butter, jelly, and bread

Tags: bread, jelly, peanut-butter

Is there a reason why, at least in the US, that:

1) on dry bread, we typically eat peanut butter AND jelly, not one or the other;

2) but on toast, we typically eat either peanut butter OR jelly, not both?

Comment: Must be your family or region. The straight up PB or J sandwich is not uncommon at my house. Practically speaking, PB&J on toast is much messier than PB or J on toast, with the jelly sliding off the warmed peanut butter in the open-face format. Seems like a somewhat low-quality/verging on off-topic question.

Comment: Um... where did that come from? I grew up eating plain PB sandwiches with no jelly... untoasted.

Comment: @Catija, how did you deal with mouth weld? Whenever I've had PB on untoasted bread it's taken extreme measured to get my mouth open again.

Comment: @GdD Using a more robust bread (e.g. whole wheat instead of white, or simply thicker slices) tends to make an untoasted peanut butter sandwich easier to eat.

Comment: Not sure what makes this a “low-quality” question. The history of peanut butter in the US is entangled with its development as a profitable commercial crop. Likewise, it would not surprise me to hear that PB&J sandwiches were invented or at least promoted by a business that had PB or J interests (which accounts for many other dietary habits in the US). Hence the question.

Comment: PB AND J on a warm slice of toast will be a melty-mess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is mostly just "it's tradition", as with most questions like this.

I do think the pattern you've described isn't quite the actual one. What really happens is that we tend to eat peanut butter *and* jelly on sandwiches, and put one or the other on single slices of bread, because with a sandwich you can spread one thing on each half and put them together, but with a single slice of bread it's messy. Sandwiches might be on toasted bread, though - untoasted is common and easier but plenty of people like toasted bread for sandwiches. Similarly, there are certainly lazy people out there who'll just spread something on a slice of untoasted bread.

Beyond that, it's just what we do.

Answer (score 0):

Within my household, growing up, I often had just peanut butter in a sandwich. Just jelly generally didn't happen for a simple reason, that without the peanut-butter first placed on the bread, the jelly would soak through. The same logic was present for peanut butter and honey sandwiches, or jelly and cream-cheese, and this was why I generally never had a tuna sandwich packed in my lunch unless there was lettuce protecting the bread.