# Peanut butter and Jelly sandwich - adapted to ingredients from the UK

Tags: jelly, peanut-butter, american-cuisine, regional-cuisine

Making a peanut butter and jelly sandwich in the UK.  What is required, what is traditional, and what is optional?

Firstly: what type of bread?  Must it be white, brown, wholemeal or granary? Are there any significant differences between bread in the US and UK?

Secondly:  Butter, margarine, nothing.  Should I butter my bread before adding other spreads? ([Idiomatic combinations of peanut butter, jelly, and bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56030/idiomatic-combinations-of-peanut-butter-jelly-and-bread) suggests nothing)  I guess it is peanut butter on one slice and jelly on the other.

Thirdly:  Crunchy or smooth peanut butter.  These are the two types that are generally available in the UK - is it the same in the US?  Is one type preferred, or is it a matter of taste?

Fourthly: Jelly.  I'm aware that this is the jam-like spread (and not the gelatine-based substance)  but what flavour?  In my local supermarket I can find "seedless raspberry jam" and (in a section for sauces to serve with meat) "redcurrant jelly".  Are either of these acceptable approximations of the concord grape jelly that I understand is traditional? How much jelly should I use: a thin scrape or layered on thickly?

Finally: Am I overthinking this?

Comment: We have all learned about the importance of [exact instructions for that P&J Sandwich](https://youtu.be/cDA3_5982h8), nevertheless I think you may  be overthinking this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a serious question, if it is you are definitely overthinking it. Just use whatever jam you like the taste of, there's no rules. But butter? Yuck!

Comment: You see I genuinely didn't expect that! - I would have thought it would be "you must use this type of jam and this type of bread"  but whether or not to use butter would be "well whatever".  So, yes, genuine question.  I've often heard of PB&J sandwiches.  But I'm never really been sure of what they really are.  It is something so very very American that you probably think it is obvious.  But it really isn't obvious if you haven't been brought up in in the US.  Try not to assume your region cuisine is obvious to someone not from your region!

Comment: I would suggest "are the differences in bread between the US and UK" is too many questions in one. I (american) am also not familiar with what "wholemeal" or "granary" bread is but any is fine, but it's usually cheap bread, but I've occasionally made "elevated" PB&Js with fnacy bread.

Comment: People are thinking it's obvious what it is because the name literally describes it. There's no additional mystery. Are sandwiches in the UK usually so specific in their ingredients when their name is something like that? Don't y'all have BLTs and grilled cheese sandwiches and stuff like that?

Comment: Also note that beyond the chunky/smooth axis there is also the homogenized/"natural" and salted/unsalted variables. Natural peanut butter on multigrain vs. Jif on white bread makes two very different sandwiches.

Comment: I have had commercial grape jelly in the UK, but it was practically tasteless compared to what I've had in the US. When I made some from tasty but slightly sharp home grown grapes it was much better

Comment: I have no idea why, but for some reason, when I read this question, I assumed that you were an American visiting the UK, and you wanted a familiar food from back home, and for some reason you were very worried about getting it right. Maybe it would be a good idea to mention that you're British and you'd like to try this American sandwich.

Comment: @TannerSwett, its just one of those things that is so American.  I would never have thought of combining nut butter and jam as a child, But because it is so obvious, nobody ever actually explains it.  Actually I wondered this from reading http://limbero.org/jl8/218 in which an "artisinal PB&J restaurant" is a gag, and I thought I'm not really "getting" the context, since I don't really know what it is.  So I tried making it (with butter of course) and its kind of what I expected- very sweet and heavy: but I wasn't sure if I had it right, I'd heard that the jelly was different in the US.

Comment: @TjadenHess I think you have just explained why the popular bathroom and kitchen cleaning products named "Jif" in th UK changed their name to "Cif".

Comment: Even within the tiny sphere of my middle-school friends in late 1970s suburban Chicago, the peanut butter & jelly sandwich I ate was very different from the ones my friends ate. You might as well ask how to adapt "pizza" to UK ingredients.  Also: Butter or margarine? Ick.

Comment: The most important part is that you _must_ cut it into triangles (from one corner of the sandwich to the other so you get two triangles) not any other shape.

Comment: @user3067860 A a representative of the Rectangular Cut Society, I must inform you that you are wading into murky waters, here, and that religious violence may follow. :P

Comment: @JamesK "The" peanut butter and jelly sandwich is a Depression Era food.  The point is not to be fine dining, but to provide a lot of calories for not very much money.  Don't overthink it---you really can't go wrong.

Comment: I believe there is also the minor detail of construction.  The common procedure of "Spread PB on one slice of bread, spread J another slice of bread, combine the two slices into a sandwich." works perfectly adequately for a sandwich to-be-eaten immediately, but many prefer the "Lightly spread PB on each of two slices of bread, carefully spread/layer J over the PB on one of those slices, combine..." method for a picnic/sack-lunch/etc. so that the PB layers prevent the J from making the bread too soggy over the hours between sandwich construction and sandwich consumption.

Comment: The general gist of comments seems to be 'don't over think it, its a sandwich how difficult can it be, you can't go wrong .... what do you mean you put butter on it you absolute heathen!'

Comment: Actually, I wonder if the butter layer thing is a british thing. One of the former Top Gear/Current Grand tour presenters, James May has a cooking show that includes making sandwiches and there's always a layer of Ludpak spreadable butter on it

Comment: Yes,  I'd always use butter.  It goes without saying. As Rosie F says  "by default, it's assumed (in default of anything to the contrary) that a sandwich's named ingredients will be between slices of bread spread with something. That something is traditionally butter, but might instead be margarine, sunflower spread or olive spread"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Firstly: what type of bread? Must it be white, brown, wholemeal or granary? Are there any significant differences between bread in the US and UK?

- It must be robust enough to hold up against wetness of the jelly without soaking through, but not tough enough that it's a jaw workout, which would cause the ingredients to splurt out the sides.
- It must be moist enough to hold up against the stickiness of the peanut butter in your mouth, but not so wet that it folds over in your hands as you try to hold it like a soggy thin-crust New York pizza.
- It should be mild enough that nothing in the bread itself overpowers the taste of the peanut butter and jelly.

This rules out some breads—a good baguette, for instance, is too tough; Hostess white bread is too feeble and soaks through; caraway-heavy ryes are too intense; and oily garlic-herbed focaccia is right out—but there's plenty of room for variation.

An English muffin—this is what Americans call your “muffins”—works fine.
A brioche roll will make PB&J into a dessert; a sandwich rye bread without caraway will make PB&J into a savory meal.
A typical multigrain sandwich bread is a good choice: not bland like a white or whole wheat bread, but not too intense on its own to overpower the main course.

> Secondly: Butter, margarine, nothing. Should I butter my bread before adding other spreads?

It's PEANUT BUTTER and JELLY, not PEANUT, BUTTER, and JELLY, silly.

The only reason there's no *law* against this is that nobody in the history of PB&J sandwiches has ever even contemplated violating such a law.

(If you're tempted to add butter, your bread is probably too dry or tough.
Sandwiches around here are lubricated with mayonnaise by default, not with butter—and definitely not margarine.
But nobody would ever dream of doing this with PB&J.)

> Thirdly: Crunchy or smooth peanut butter. These are the two types that are generally available in the UK - is it the same in the US? Is one type preferred, or is it a matter of taste?

Matter of taste.

Note: Peanut butter is a mixture of ground peanuts and, optionally, salt.
Period (full stop).
Any other ingredients—like sugar, palm oil, hydrogenated dog snot, or who knows what other balderdash the private equity barons have stooped to adding—make it an abomination upon humankind.
If it doesn't separate naturally, it's been desecrated by evil.
(Store it upside-down to make stirring easier when you open it.)

You can use unsalted peanut butter, but salted peanut butter will make the whole thing taste stronger.
You can always add salt when you stir it if you got unsalted peanut butter.

> Fourthly: Jelly. I'm aware that this is the jam-like spread (and not the gelatine-based substance) but what flavour? In my local supermarket I can find "seedless raspberry jam" and (in a section for sauces to serve with meat) "redcurrant jelly". Are either of these acceptable approximations of the concord grape jelly that I understand is traditional?

Any flavo(u)r you like, although redcurrant or cranberry are probably too tart for the job.
Personally I like elderberry best, but strawberry, raspberry, blueberry, and grape are all reasonable choices.
Your seedless raspberry jam will do just fine!

> How much jelly should I use: a thin scrape or layered on thickly?

Taste differ, but to me the important thing is for the jelly to lubricate the peanut butter and not to be a sugary fruit soup that you dropped your bread in.
Too much and it will squirt out the sides.
Try a gradient of a thin scrape at one end to a thicker layer at the other end to see what you like.

> Finally: Am I overthinking this?

Absolutely not!

Source: an American who spent formative years subsisting on peanut butter and jelly sandwiches for lunch (and sometimes dinner).

Comment: As to butter, the OP seems to have parsed the phrase correctly. It's just that, by default, it's assumed (in default of anything to the contrary) that a sandwich's named ingredients will be between slices of bread spread with *something*. That something is traditionally butter, but might instead be margarine, sunflower spread or olive spread, for example. And you typically *don't* list it when you specify a sort of sandwich. So mentioning peanut butter in the name might give the impression that it's as well as, rather than instead of.

Comment: Yes, living in the south UK ALL sandwiches have some kind of butter spread by default, which just goes without saying. You butter then bread, then add the filling (peanut butter, jam, tuna, honey, ham, whatever).

Comment: There's a reason "PB with palm kernel oil" is so popular: *natural* PB is a stiff, separated hassle.  Long live Peter Pan!!!

Comment: I have never heard of putting butter on a PB&J, as someone who has lived in the US.  I don't think that it is an offense against the culinary arts to do so (especially if you toast the bread--not "normal" but something that happens sometimes), but it certainly is not normal in the US.  There is plenty of oil already in the PB.

Comment: Actually "muffin" can mean either a large cupcake, or a disc-shaped soft bread roll - though this form is most familiar from McDonalds and other similar American outlets.

Comment: Great answer on everything except the J! In the UK, J must stand for jam in this setting. Raspberry or strawberry would be good choices (with or without the seeds), but that redcurrant jelly was in the section for sauces to serve with meat for a reason. Leave it there.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the best way to eat peanut butter is on a piece of buttered toast. Chunky PB is preferable, and the toast should still be warm when eaten. Jelly is optional. I'm surprised so many people have never heard of this.

Comment: "a good baguette, for instance, is too tough" I wish I had enough rep to downvote your answer for this heresy. The strictness about PB ingredients almost compensates, though.

Comment: You can't really get muffins in the UK except at McDonald's. The 'English Muffin' is a complete misnomer. If you asked for a muffin over here, you'd get a 'bun' (cupcake)[& even the muffin in that is imported from the US; I guess we had a choice of two items the same word could belong to, we chose the other one.] For those not in the know, the difference between a bun & a muffin is they put more batter in a muffin so it flows over the top a bit ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin If that was true, I wouldn't currently have a pack of muffins sitting in my freezer.  All the shops around here sell them in the bread section.  It is, however, regionally dependant; up in Yorkshire and Lancashire, for example, you are more likely to find teacakes than muffins — or even a stotty if you go further north towards the Scottish border…

Comment: (Although, referring to them as "English Muffins" might, from that perspective, be a matter of over-generalisation — akin to referring to the Colonel's fare as "[American Fried Chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KFC)")

Comment: Echoing @RonJohn: while some people may believe that "peanut butter with more than peanuts and salt is an abomination", it's definitely a minority opinion in the U.S., if we are measuring by sales figures.

Comment: @MJ713 American here. I tried that kind of peanut butter once. Never again. imo it needs at least a bit of sugar, and is even better with palm oil.

Comment: @Showsni "You butter then bread, then add the filling (peanut butter, [...other fillings...])"  Butter _and_ peanut butter?  What's the benefit?

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson strawberry jam is quite popular in the US in PBJ sandwiches.

Comment: @Esther when just snacking that odd spoonful of peanut butter... sure, sugar makes it even more of a guilty pleasure! But when combined with jelly, any sugar in the PB doesn't really make much difference. IMO it's better to avoid the sugar there. As for palm oil, that obviously does help with spreadability and perhaps you also prefer the mouth-feel – but these should also be fine with the pure-peanuts variant if it has been thoroughly re-stirred from its separated state. Palm oil does have [some issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_and_environmental_impact_of_palm_oil) to think about.

Comment: @Chronocidal - I found them in Asda & Sainsbury's online - never see them in the shops themselves. They seem to be only available in the 'economy' range. Have you considered they're actually just copies of the US ones, inspired by McDonald's, rather than being 'British'?

Comment: @lessthanideal ' Butter and peanut butter? What's the benefit?' Tastiness.

Comment: @Tetsujin My understanding is that they were invented *in America* by an Englishman, but that there is a third type of muffin, now known as the oven-bottom muffin, to distinguish it from the griddled muffin. What Americans call English Muffins are a relatively recent introduction to the UK scene, as are the high-fat batter sweet muffins, but the Muffin-man of Drury Lane was selling *something* and that rhyme was first recorded in 1820.

Comment: @Spagirl - that makes sense to me - they're as 'English' as chicken tikka masala is 'Indian' or doner kebabs are 'Turkish' ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin döner kebab _is_ Turkish. What's not Turkish is the sandwich form in which it's most commonly eaten across Europe.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - I'm sure this over-extended comment thread could get more pedantic if we all tried really hard. Until very recently, none of the Turkish places [& I live in an area very heavily influenced by many Turkish immigrants] near me ever used pitta, but there seems to be a recent revival, actually known as 'authentic German doner' though some of them have a very odd idea as to what constitutes one - https://www.germandonerkebab.com/menu [Never eaten there, never likely to.] Where I grew up [70s, Northern England], all doners were  meat ,salad & pitta, no 'actual' Turkish food at all

Comment: @Tetsujin Uh, excuse me? What is chicken tikka masala if not Indian?

Comment: @just-a-hriday - actually invented in Glasgow.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope. I'm Indian, I know my culture. Yes, an Indian _living_ in Britain created it, but the dish's flavours, methods, and also name (no brit could have named something "tikka masala") are firmly rooted in Indian cuisine.

Comment: @just-a-hriday - I'm still not sure what you are trying to tell me. We were discussing foods that aren't actually from where most people think they are.  We could add ramen to that list. We could add the travesty Coronation Chicken too, invented by a culinary student in London.

Answer (score 18):

Although yes, much of it is a matter of personal preference, I will try to give some constructive advice:

1. You want a ‘sandwich bread’.  Something that’s cut relatively thin (1cm or less) with a relatively tight crumb (no large holes from bubbles) and not so soft that it’s going to shred if you try to smear it with your peanut butter, but not something so tough that you have to tear it off with your teeth.  You also don’t want anything with too assertive of a flavor (rye with caraway, sourdough, brioche, etc).  Whole wheat is fine, but a white bread is more typical.  I personally like something like a cracked wheat or multigrain bread.
2. I have no idea how US bread compare to UK, but I do know that
   there’s a style of bread in the US that’s mass produced by injecting
   air into the dough rather than letting it ferment naturally, and I
   suspect that much of our factory made bread is of this type.
3. The amount and type of peanut butter is a personal preference.  But beware of putting on too much, as it will glue your mouth together.
4. Jam / jelly is also a personal preference.  The two most common in the US are grape and strawberry, but grape can be a controversial flavor (as it’s Concord grapes, not a wine or table grape).  But you can use whatever variety you like.  I personally like cherry jam, but will go with grape or strawberry if that’s what’s available.  (In the US, jam might include skins, jelly is strained jam or just made from juice, sugar, and pectin)
5. The jelly  needs to be proportional to the amount of peanut butter used, but you have to beware of too much, or it will squirt out of the back as you’re eating it.
6. Depending on the type of bread and how far ahead you’re making it, some jam will soak into the bread.  This isn’t always a good thing, as softer breads will slowly dissolve and if you’ve got something hard in with it, the sandwich will bruise and you end up with the dreaded ‘purple sided sandwich’ where the jelly soaks through to the outside.
7. It might seem like a good idea to put peanut butter on both slices of bread to avoid the bruised sandwich, but this makes it so the jelly has nothing to grip to and more likely that it’s going to squirt out the back when you eat it.

You can replace the jelly with other sweet things.  Honey, banana slices, chocolate sprinkles, marshmallow fluff, etc.  Although that would make them no longer ‘peanut butter and jelly’.  Some marmelades can work, but some are so chunky that it just makes it weird and chewy.

Likewise, you can also replace the peanut butter with other nut butters (almond, cashew, etc) so long as it’s soft enough to spread without damaging the bread.

Comment: Sourdough works great for a PB&J. Maybe not the kind with the tough crust, but the kind that comes sliced for sandwiches is fine.

Comment: You write about air injected into dough. Do you mean using baking powder / soda instead of yeast? If this is something else, could you clarify, please?

Comment: Two other solid options to replace the jam/jelly: Bacon or pickles. Peanut butter and bacon on toasted bread is soooooo good.

Comment: Smooth strawberry is probably the best you'll easily find in the UK, or maybe plum.

Comment: @CGCampbell See number 7

Comment: @Simppa no, as I understand it ‘a a pressure chamber where they do the mixing, so extra air in trapped into the dough without having to wait for fermentation to happen.  There used to be a British company named the ‘Aerated Bread Company’ so it’s possible that it still exists over the pond, too.

Comment: "grape can be a controversial flavor (as it’s Concord grapes, not a wine or table grape)".  Eh?

Comment: @RonJohn If you've only had normal grapes...like you bought grapes at the store and at them...then US grape jelly will not taste right since it's a different type of grape that tastes different. Some people don't realize it's a different type of grape and think that the difference in flavor is because of the process or something that makes it taste "weird". This is the same as banana candy flavor--people wonder why someone would think it tastes like banana without realizing that the point of comparison was actually a different type of banana that tasted more like that flavor.

Comment: "mass produced by injecting air".  I'm ***really dubious*** at that assertion.  (It would cause large, irregular bubbles in the bread, and that's been verboten for 50 years.)

Comment: @RonJohn they dissolve it into the water before mixing.  See https://blogs.bl.uk/science/2018/05/world-baking-day-two-british-advances-in-baking-technology.html ; but after some research seems that the US now mostly uses something they call “no time bread’ while the UK uses something called the “Chorleywood process”

Comment: Dissolving CO2 in water is utterly and completely different from "injecting air into the dough".

Answer (score 12):

Two major differences between the USA and the UK are in terms of the bread and in terms of the peanut butter. Both of these described as a foreigner (though from a British colony) in both countries and one who hasn't visited the UK for a long time (>10 years). I have no affiliation with any of the companies/brands mentioned and none of them should be taken as an endorsement of the products.

In the USA, almost all supermarket bread brands (e.g Sara Lee, Nature's Own, Pepperidge Farms, Arnold) is particularly soft and very odd flavour. As far as I can tell this is from having added lactic acid and quite a lot of sugar. I would describe the texture as similar to a pancake; if you squash it, it will not rebound and has little gluten development in it. I don't have any comparison for the taste. From my experience, in the UK, this bread would rank very low in the scale of breads available, being of worse quality (texture and flavour) than the cheapest brands.

Conversely, in the UK, supermarket bread (e.g. Hovis, Sainsbury's), is firmer, with a more defined crumb and a more yeasty taste. The texture is similar to a top-end supermarket bread in the USA, but the flavour is different; lacking the lactic-acid taste and a lot of sweetness compared to the USA.

For the PB. While you can get it without, almost all USA peanut butters contain some measure of sugar (e.g. [Skippy](https://www.peanutbutter.com/peanut-butter/creamy)). This is often the second ingredient on the list, and is somewhere above the 2% mark that seems to be the cut-off for special listing. As I am used to peanut butters being made from peanuts, oil and salt; this is quite sweet on its own. It seems that some UK brands have sugar included (e.g. [Sainsbury's](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/product/aldi-price-match/sainsburys-crunchy-peanut-butter--basics-340g)), but this is normally 3rd or 4th on the list, after oil(s). Most PB brands in the UK seemed to have only peanuts, oil(s) and salt as the ingredients.

If I were to make a PB&J in the UK, aiming to get it as similar to the ones I had in the USA as possible, I would get a sweetened PB, use strawberry jam, and use a very soft, thick-cut (toast) bread.

Comment: I just squeezed a slice of US mass market bread, and it rebounded quite nicely.

Comment: @RonJohn I did say "squash" rather than squeeze, as in press firmly. Mass market bread in much of the world (including my country) will not rebound from a squash, but will from a squeeze. Decent breads (e.g from a specialist bread shop or similar) will resist squashing and rebound from even a strong press.

Comment: Who in the world *squashes* bread?  That's... foolish.

Comment: No, wait: *pretentious people* squash bread, and then say how great it is.

Comment: @RonJohn squashing can be accidental - say in a bag with other items from a supermarket. Not all the world bags 2 items per (plastic) bag as the USA seems to. Or perhaps if you were wanting to compare breads across types or looking for a texture that you prefer, it might be a metric by which you could measure this.

Comment: Even back in the days of large paper grocery bags (I'm that old), we knew how to not squish bread.  Europeans must not be very smart.

Comment: And you discover a texture you like by *eating* a loaf., and either buying or not buying it again.

Comment: @RonJohn indeed eating is the primary indicator, taste and texture are a big part of the enjoyment of food - but just what do you think your teeth do when they press into the bread? Molars compress... Europeans are just as smart as anyone - after all, the majority of Americans are European in origin...

Comment: Are we talking about two different kinds of bread me: (pre-sliced loaf bread, and you: unsliced crusty bread)?

Answer (score 9):

Any combination of the choices you listed (even the use of butter or margarine, apparently) would be fine and authentic and a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Nah, we always put butter on the jam side - it keeps the bread from getting soggy by lunch.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I think the bread is *supposed* to get soggy

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- if you are (understandably) concerned about soggy bread, then smear a *thin* layer of PB on the bread before adding the jelly.

Comment: the main purpose of the butter under jam or honey is to try and fill the holes in the bread (something american would have no idea about, though. American bread doesn't have holes, I won't speculate as to why)

Comment: @njzk2 I'm looking at a piece of American bread right now.  It's full of gas holes.  (Their just too small to "pierce" the slices.  We figured out the fix for that 50 years ago.)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Everyone is entitled to their opinion I suppose

Comment: @RonJohn Nah, I like the flavor of the butter (when I ate butter).

Comment: @RonJohn were you part of the team of adventurous bakers who pierced the secret of small holes in the bread? Or is the general chauvinist "we"?

Comment: @njzk2 it's the same "we" as in "we won the war", even though my father was still a suckling babe when the war ended.  But you knew that...

Comment: @RonJohn what I didn't know was that bread needed fixing. Thank you for figuring that out!

Comment: @njzk2 thank the people who figured out how to bake sandwich bread that doesn't have *big* holes in it.  It was a great and important achievent.

Comment: @RonJohn indeed. But are you sure it's that recent? Surely Lord Sandwich didn't have mayonnaise running down his fingers when he was playing cards

Comment: @njzk2 it was the late 1960s.  (I remember that Bunny Bread had a promotion in 1970/1971 saying that any child who found a hole through a slice of bread would get a party for his/her whole classroom.  A classmate found a hole, and we got a party.)

Comment: @RonJohn haha, quite a nice story actually!

Answer (score 9):

You're definitely overthinking it. There are many variations based on personal preference, but there are some traditions.

Generally when people think about PB&J sandwiches made for young children, you use very soft and cheap white bread, sometimes even with the crusts cut off. You would usually use smooth peanut butter, and jelly that's pretty close to what you call jelly in the UK, a bit thicker but no seeds or lumps of fruit, and sort of artificial flavors. When people get nostalgic for peanut butter and jelly sandwiches, it's often this early childhood version.

As kids get older and don't care so much about lumpy food, you see more variety of bread with more grains, sometimes crunchy peanut butter, and more jam or preserves than jelly. Many adults don't eat PB&J anymore, but if they do, it's usually this version with more texture.

Comment: Not only are PB&Js made *for* young kids, they are often made *by* young kids.  While I am sure that there is someone out there who is selling "elevated" sandwiches for thirty bucks a each, an "authentic" PB&J is quite simple and easy to make. :D

Comment: Just a note:  "Jelly" in the UK generally refers to what most Americans would call "Jello"; a sweetened gelatin dessert.  "Jam" is what is spread on sandwiches, much like American jam.  The standard American jelly is not commonly available in the UK.

Comment: you seem to assume that PB&J is a kids' food?

Comment: @njzk2 While there are versions of the PB&J which appeal to more adult palettes, I would conjecture that the *vast* majority of these sandwiches are made for children.  Yes.  The PB&J is kids' food.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are very much overthinking this.

#### Traditional Peanut Butter and Jelly

In the United States, the peanut butter and jelly sandwich (PB&J) is a quick, easy meal, usually made for a small child (and often made *by* a small child).  Thus a "traditional" PB&J is likely to be relatively bland (many small children don't like more complicated textures or flavors), rather sweet, and very easy to make (most American children can probably slap together a PB&J by the time they are six or seven years old).

Moreover, the PB&J is something of a "poverty food"—it is a food often associated with low-income dining.  Indeed, PB&J sandwiches [rose to popularity during the Great Depression](https://www.nationalpeanutboard.org/news/who-invented-the-peanut-butter-and-jelly-sandwich.htm) as a very affordable, calorie dense food.  As such, the ingredients tend to be quite inexpensive, which tends to imply more artificial flavors, neat food science tricks (like partially-hydrogenated oils to improve textures), and the liberal use of subsidized ingredients (like high fructose corn syrup).

Thus you can expect the following from a traditional PB&J:

1. **Sandwich Bread:**  A traditional PB&J is made with something like [Wonder Bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Bread).  Wonder Bread is an exemplar of a certain style of mass-produced American bread:  it has little structure, a fair amount of sugar (in the form of high fructose corn syrup), and is leavened mostly chemically (e.g. with baking soda and lactic acid) and mechanically (through the action of steam as it cooks).
2. **Peanut Butter:**  The most widely available peanut butters in the US are things like [Jif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jif_(peanut_butter)) and [Skippy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_(peanut_butter)).  Historically, peanut butter was made from roasted peanuts and salt---the problem with this recipe is that the solids tend to separate from the fats, which is kind of a pain.  The innovation of the brands listed above is that they include partially- or fully-hydrogenated oils, which prevent the mixture from separating, and gives these brands a very smooth texture.  These brands also add a fairly significant amount of sugar.  While they come in "chunky" varieties, a traditional PB&J probably uses the "creamy" kind, which has been processed to the point that it has no real texture—again, small children tend not to like texture all that much.
3. **Jelly (Jam):**  The jelly in a PB&J is likely to be something like [Smucker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_J.M._Smucker_Company) or [Welch's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s) grape jelly (note that what we Americans call "jelly" is probably understood in the UK as "jam").
   The expectation is that the jelly will be smooth (i.e. without seeds), thick (there is likely going to be a fair amount of pectin involved), a fair amount of sugar (again, probably high fructose corn syrup), and artificial flavors.

In terms of ingredients, *that's it*.  Keep it simple.

**Preparation:**  The preparation is very simple:  grab two slices of bread, spread peanut butter on one slice (or both—when I was a child, I figured out that if I spread peanut butter on both slices of bread, the peanut butter would protect the bread from getting soggy, so I could pack a sandwich in the morning, and it would still be appealing by lunchtime at school), spread jelly on that, and put the sandwich together.  Again, this is something that a small child is expected to be able to do—the amounts of peanut butter and jelly can vary wildly, from almost none to way too much.

#### Theme and Variation

I've said this multiple times already, but it bears repetition:  the PB&J is an American comfort food, meant to be cheap and appealing to children.  You really shouldn't think too hard about it.

However, this also means that there is no need to stick too strictly to the guidelines listed above.  Parents buy the ingredients they can get at the grocery store (which can vary a lot depending on local conditions and income level) and that they can expect their children to eat.  When those children grow up, they make their own nostalgic version of the PB&J they remember from childhood.

Don't like grape jelly?  Cool—use raspberry or blueberry or red current or blackberry or whatever you like.  Prefer chunky peanut butter?  Great—go for it!  Or don't use peanut butter at all—try some other nut butter, like cashew or almond.  Want bread with more texture?  Sure!  Use whatever bread you like—it is entirely up to your tastes.

Personally, my favorite version of the peanut butter and jelly sandwich is made with unsweetened chunky peanut butter (which usually means getting "organic" or "natural" peanut butter at the grocery) and apricot jam on Jewish rye.

---

NB:  The references to specific brands are *very* intentional here.  Part of the nostalgia of a PB&J for most Americans is an association with very specific, inexpensive national brands.  These ingredients are highly processed, and have very specific flavors and textures.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly: what type of bread? Must it be white, brown, wholemeal or granary? Are there any significant differences between bread in the US and UK?

In general, the type of bread you would use for a sandwich where the contents of the sandwich are supposed to be the dominant flavor.

The ‘ideal’ bread is soft (baguettes are too crispy for example), moderately dry, moderately dense (you want the air bubbles to mostly be small and relatively uniform, so not something like ciabatta), and mildly flavored.

The ‘classic’ PB&J would have been made with cheap white bread.

Pre-sliced multigrain wheat will will often work well too. Rye or pumpernickel may work, but ire a bit stronger flavored than most Americans would expect. Good pita bread (sometimes called ‘Greek bread’ in the UK I believe), while not traditional, also works well in my experience.

> Secondly: Butter, margarine, nothing. Should I butter my bread before adding other spreads? (Idiomatic combinations of peanut butter, jelly, and bread suggests nothing) I guess it is peanut butter on one slice and jelly on the other.

No butter, margarine, or any other such toppings. We simply don’t really butter bread for sandwiches here in the US (mayonnaise is the norm if we need to soften the bread a bit), but even if we did, a PB&J already has enough oil and water in the ingredients that the bread should not need to be buttered. You also generally should not toast the bread either (if it’s too dry it won’t do well with the moisture from the jelly).

> Thirdly: Crunchy or smooth peanut butter. These are the two types that are generally available in the UK - is it the same in the US? Is one type preferred, or is it a matter of taste?

Primarily a matter of taste. You can, in theory, even substitute other nut butters for peanut butter, though based on my own experimentation the only alternative to peanut butter that works well in terms of taste is cashew butter (all the other nut butters I’ve tried were either too bland, or ended up too sweet).

> Fourthly: Jelly. I'm aware that this is the jam-like spread (and not the gelatine-based substance) but what flavour? In my local supermarket I can find "seedless raspberry jam" and (in a section for sauces to serve with meat) "redcurrant jelly". Are either of these acceptable approximations of the concord grape jelly that I understand is traditional? How much jelly should I use: a thin scrape or layered on thickly?

‘Jelly’ *is* jam, but with the fruit pulp filtered out (so it’s less ‘chunky’). That ‘seedless’ raspberry jam is probably actually jelly, not jam.

As far as the actual choice of flavor for the jelly, it should be:

- Primarily sweet, and slightly tart, but not savory (the peanut butter is supposed to contribute the savory aspect).
- Relatively ‘bold’ in terms of flavor. Delicate flavors just don’t work as well here.
- Something *you* actually like.

You’re correct that grape jelly is the traditional option (though the fact that it’s concord grape jelly has less to do with taste and more to do with historical availability of grape cultivars in the US), but all kinds of other flavors work. Blueberry jelly is relatively popular around where I live. When I was a kid I often had raspberry or blackberry jelly instead, and always liked the blackberry better than the raspberry because it had a stronger flavor. These days I prefer lingonberry jam or Key lime marmalade (the first because I just love lingonberry jam, and the second because I love citrus but orange marmalade is not quite strong enough for my tastes in terms of flavor). One of my friends swears by cranberry jelly, and a couple of my friends love using sour cherry jam. I even know people who use apple butter or fig butter instead of jelly.

The only types of jelly I’ve tried on a PB&J that I would consider truly not suited for it are mint jelly and hagebuttermark (a Swabian jelly made from rose hips), and both were cases where the flavors just didn’t blend all that well with the peanut butter flavor. I would also expect tomato and pepper jellies to not work very well either for the same reasons.

> Finally: Am I overthinking this?

Probably, but overthinking things on occasion is not always a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

From someone raise (mostly) in the United States, the answer is pretty much going to be -- do whatever is most-similar to what you are familiar with.

My mother prepared PB&J sandwiches with JIF extra-crunchy peanut butter, raspberry preserves, and "Jewish" rye bread. I would go to my friends' houses and be served store-brand smooth peanut butter (or, occasionally, honey-nut spread) with strawberry or concord grape jelly on Wonder bread and my reaction would be -- "ew, gross, this isn't PB&J." *My* experience of PB&J is what it is; my elementary school friends would beg to differ.

Crossing an ocean, the facts remain true. Ingredient substitution is going to depend on what a "peanut butter and jelly sandwich" *means* to you.

> Finally: Am I overthinking this?

No, you're not over-thinking. But this is one of those situations where the dish and *what it means to you* -- especially any emotional connections to a specific preparation -- means that there's no one real answer.

We can tell you the differences between jelly, jam, preserves, and how these terms translate across the pond; or discuss different brands of peanut butters, preparations, and spreads. But at the end of the day, finding a cognate that means "home" to you is going to be a very intensely personal and unique experience, and what works for me won't necessarily work for you.